# How to install previous version of an ios app?

Tags: ios

I've developed an ios app, but now I got some crash reports which says that the app is crashing only when updated from a previous version and it goes away when uninstalling and then reinstalling that app altogether.

So I decided to reproduce the crash by going back to the older version doing some stuff and then updating it back to the latest build.

The thing is reverting back to an old commit for a switching back to the older version of the app is causing quite a lot of issues and errors which I'm unable to resolve as of now. So is there any way besides this to install the older version of the app.
I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 4, while the previous version was built on Swift 2.3 and an older Xcode, my Testflight app only has the latest builds while there is nothing backed up on iTunes too.

Comment: How do your users install the old version of the app? Or is that method no longer an option for them or you? (for instance, on the app store, via an enterprise distribution, etc)

Comment: The user may have been on the older version and may have not updated the app itself but as soon as they update to the newer version, a particular crash is occurring, which I was trying to reproduce. From my side, I just update & release the app with new version numbers like a normal app release, so I don't have access to my previous app version/builds.

Comment: "so I don't have access to my previous app version/builds" Yes you do. You cannot update and release without making an archive. That archive _is_ the previous app version. See my answer below.

Comment: No Archives is what I find when I open the Archive section from the Organizer window @matt

Comment: Well then you're up a creek without a paddle. What did you do with the archives? Every time you choose Product -> Archive, you get an archive. If you haven't deleted them, they should all be there. Or did you do the archiving on some other machine? If so, you need to get the archive from that machine.

Comment: Actually, I've taken over as an ios developer from someone else so the machine that I got was a formatted one, plus I happen to be a newbie on IOS development and a fresher as well, so I don't have much idea about it. Maybe my predecessor misplaced those archives unintentionally, but the fact of the matter is I don't have them right now and I'm stuck now on this weird situation, literally up a creek without a paddle.

Answer (score 5):

> The thing is reverting back to an old commit for a switching back to the older version of the app is causing quite a lot of issues and errors which I'm unable to resolve as of now

Ah, but that's not how to do it. What you want to do is *not* recompile the old version from *source*; you want the already compiled old version as an actual app. That is exactly what the archive is for! The reason we keep archives is so as to have the exact same already compiled code that has been distributed thru the store.

So just go to the Organizer window, find your old archive, and export it as an Ad Hoc build. Now you can install that on your device through the Devices window, play around with it, and then install the new version on top of it and run that and (one hopes) reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get what you're saying and that's absolutely correct way too, but as I said, there is nothing archived, unfortunately, so I cannot download that from the Organizer window. Though, now I can see the crash from the Organizer window.

Comment: You do not "download" anything. The archives are all right there on your machine (or whatever machine you performed the archive action on).

Comment: The ad hoc ipa cannot be installed on the simulator only a real device. Is there any way to install an older app version to the simulator?

Comment: @David If you have a different question please ask it _as a question_, not in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A crash like this is almost always caused by data that is no longer compatible from the first version of the app.

If you don't have access to the compiled binary and don't have a way to re-install it, then your best bet is to install an old version of Xcode to install the old version of the app, and then use the new version of Xcode to install the new version of the app over it.

You may run into issues with the old version of Xcode not supporting your newer iOS version on your device. In that case, use the old version of Xcode to install the app to the simulator. Then in Xcode you open Window -> Devices and Simulators. You can download the sandbox folder for your app from the device and then copy over the exact files to a device with the new version of the app. Then when you run the new app you should be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Actually, I have a rough idea about the crash. You are right, it is most probably caused due to change in format of the data I'm storing in UserDefaults in my previous version compared to my current version of the app. I'll try to implement your suggestion and will then come back to you, thanks for the help.